# Removing character From String XML tag's Attribute in PHP

Tags: php, json, xml, parsing

I have a XML String ,facing one trouble in Removing of :  **ok\"=""**
 From attribute of XML Tag 
My XML Code is

`<qbxml>\n<qbxmlmsgsrs>\n<companyqueryrs statuscode="\&quot;0\&quot;" statusseverity="\&quot;Info\&quot;" statusmessage="\&quot;Status" ok\"="">\n<companyret>\n<issamplecompany>false</issamplecompany>\n<companyname>Cougar Enterprises Hosted</companyname>\n<legalcompanyname>COFAUD</legalcompanyname>\n<address>\n<addr1>69 Smart Street</addr1>\n<city>Melbourne</city>\n<state>VIC</state>\n<postalcode>3001</postalcode>\n</address>\n<addressblock>\n<addr1>69 Smart Street</addr1>\n<addr2>Melbourne, VIC 3001</addr2>\n</addressblock>\n<legaladdress>\n<addr1>IDEV</addr1>\n<addr2>PLGPAUG15ANZ</addr2>\n<city>COF0058</city>\n</legaladdress>\n<phone>03 9854 1222</phone>\n<fax>03 9854 1223</fax>\n<email>Accounts@cougar.com.au</email>\n<companywebsite>www.cougar.com.au</companywebsite>\n<firstmonthfiscalyear>July</firstmonthfiscalyear>\n<firstmonthincometaxyear>July</firstmonthincometaxyear>\n<ein>98 765 432 154/</ein>\n<taxform>OtherOrNone</taxform>\n</companyret>\n</companyqueryrs>\n</qbxmlmsgsrs>\n</qbxml>`

When i am Trying to Parse this it gives me issue:
**Unable to format the JSON output. Attribute name "ok" associated with an element type "companyqueryrs" must be followed by the ' = ' character.**

I tried with **str_replace** and Regex but couldn't Find out Result.
I am  checking this Conversion on
http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-to-json-converter.html

if I remove manually **ok\"=""** from XML String then it gives me Proper results but From Scripts I am not able to Remove this One.
Can you please Suggest?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the exact code/script you're using to replace the `ok\"=""`?

Comment: @JerodJohnson I was trying to like 
str_replace(' "ok\"="','', $response_result));

Comment: Just to confirm that isn't a typo, but a copy-paste error: did you use `str_replace('"ok\"="','',$response_result);` or `str_replace('ok\"=""','',$response_result);`? (Note the leading `"` in the first example, as opposed to the trailing `"`). I just tested the line with the correct string (`ok\"=""`) here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ and it worked as expected. Is there something about your script that would require you to escape some characters? i.e.: `str_replace('ok\\\"=\"\"', ...`

Comment: @JerodJohnson , I Tried with preceding Slashed but didn't work.

Comment: @JerodJohnson Even i also tried to replace only "ok" but it couldn't find out this in values of attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
 $string = '
<qbxml>\n<qbxmlmsgsrs>\n<companyqueryrs statuscode="\&quot;0\&quot;"  statusseverity="\&quot;Info\&quot;" statusmessage="\&quot;Status" ok\"="">\n<companyret>\n<issamplecompany>false</issamplecompany>\n<companyname>Cougar Enterprises Hosted</companyname>\n<legalcompanyname>COFAUD</legalcompanyname>\n<address>\n<addr1>69 Smart Street</addr1>\n<city>Melbourne</city>\n<state>VIC</state>\n<postalcode>3001</postalcode>\n</address>\n<addressblock>\n<addr1>69 Smart Street</addr1>\n<addr2>Melbourne, VIC 3001</addr2>\n</addressblock>\n<legaladdress>\n<addr1>IDEV</addr1>\n<addr2>PLGPAUG15ANZ</addr2>\n<city>COF0058</city>\n</legaladdress>\n<phone>03 9854 1222</phone>\n<fax>03 9854 1223</fax>\n<email>Accounts@cougar.com.au</email>\n<companywebsite>www.cougar.com.au</companywebsite>\n<firstmonthfiscalyear>July</firstmonthfiscalyear>\n<firstmonthincometaxyear>July</firstmonthincometaxyear>\n<ein>98 765 432 154/</ein>\n<taxform>OtherOrNone</taxform>\n</companyret>\n</companyqueryrs>\n</qbxmlmsgsrs>\n</qbxml>';


 $string=str_replace('ok\"=""',"",$string);
 print_r($string);
```

Comment: On Console it shows String like : 

statusmessage="\&quot;Status" ok\"="">